# Problems with Swift Declaration

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just ask myself why I can't do something like this directly under my Class Declaration in Swift:

```
let width = 200.0
let height = 30.0

let widthheight = width-height
```

I can not create a constant with 2 other constants. If I use this inside a function/method everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: What you got as error? it's working here.

Comment: better to read this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1

Comment: @Mani The OP means it **inside a class**.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Sorry I misunderstood this question. I've checked inside method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `let widthheight = width - height`, this implicitly means `let widthheight = self.width - self.height`. In Swift, you're simply not allowed to use `self` until all its members have been initialised — here, including `widthheight`.

You have a little bit more flexibility in an `init` method, though, where you can write things like this:

```
class Rect {

    let width = 200.0
    let height = 30.0
    let widthheight: Double
    let widthheightInverse: Double

    init() {
        // widthheightInverse = 1.0 / widthheight // widthheight not usable yet
        widthheight = width - height
        widthheightInverse = 1.0 / widthheight // works
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a candidate for a *computed property* as such:

```
class Foo {
  let width = 200.0
  let height = 30.0
  var widthheight : Double { return width - height }
}
```

You might raise an issue of 'but it is computed each time'; perhaps your application will depend on a single subtraction done repeatedly - but not likely.  If the subtraction is an issue, set `widthheight` in `init()`

Answer (score -2):

For things like that, you could make use of class variables. The code would look like this:

```
class var width = 200.0
class var height = 30.0
class var widthheight = width - height
```

But when you try it, you will see a compiler error:

> Class variables are not yet supported

I guess they haven't implemented that feature yet. But there is a solution for now. Just move your declarations outside the class declaration, like following:

```
let width = 200.0
let height = 30.0
let widthheight = width - height

class YourClass { ...
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up different concepts altogether that don't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It's a good practice to use static(class) vars and consts in multiple languages. And it does solve the OP's problem without overriding any methods.

Comment: If the OP is trying to model fields/properties of an object: static/class fields are not appropriate, and neither are global variables.

Comment: He is trying to make them constant. Thats why they shouldn't even be bound to any instance. Constants should be kept in the type(class) scope.